# Is this templated class defined behaviour?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a strange case where a template argument is a pointer to a class object, and I have to forward declare the class, otherwise it won't compile:

```
struct Keyboard; // Forward declaration (is only here so that the below class knows what Keyboard* is
/* With a template argument of nullptr the EventReader doesn't distribute keyboard events*/
template <Keyboard* KeyboardObject>
struct EventReader
{
    void readEvents()
    {
        if (/* Event is keyboard event*/ true)
        {
            if constexpr (KeyboardObject != nullptr)
                KeyboardObject->receiveInput(4);
        }
    }
};

/* Keyboard class hasn't been defined here*/
EventReader<nullptr> eventReader;


//Keyboard keyboard;
int main()
{
/* Keyboard class hasn't been defined here either */

    eventReader.readEvents(); //
}
```

When the templated class is instantiated it knows it has a static pointer to an object of class named Keyboard, it doesn't matter that that class isn't defined anywhere? Is this because it isn't needed because when the template argument is nullptr it doesn't generate the call to the member function?

Also, I want to be sure that this pointer is not being accessed at runtime, in other words the call to KeyboardObject->receiveInput(4) is exactly the same as:

```
KeyboardObject keyboardObject1;

int main() 
{
     keyboardObject1.receiveInput(4);
}
```

Comment: Pointers to incomplete classes are allowed. `if constexpr` means that the whole branch is discarded at compile-time if the condition is false.

Comment: @super Another thing I don't get, the template is expecting a Keyboard*, though it doesn't know what that is. If I pass it a nullptr is Keyboard* nullptr_t?

Comment: From [std::nullptr_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t): _std::nullptr_t is the type of the null pointer literal, nullptr. It is a distinct type that is not itself a pointer type or a pointer to member type. Its values are null pointer constants (see NULL), and may be implicitly converted to any pointer and pointer to member type._

Comment: I.e. `nullptr` is of type `nullptr_t` but your template has a value parameter. Hence, I assume that `nullptr_t` is implicitly converted to `Keyboard*`. (I stumbled over this as I remembered there is no implicit conversion in template arguments - but that's for template type parameters...)

Comment: If you don't want the pointer to be accessed, why do you need it at all?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. It's in the case you want to initialise the event listener and not receive keyboard inputs.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Do you want to instantiate `EventReader` with a non-null pointer to `Keyboard` at some point? If so, what is the significance of "pointer is not being accessed at runtime"? How do you distinguish between the case of the pointer being accessed and the case of the pointer not being accessed?

Comment: I wrote the answer, but actually after reading the comments I am not sure anymore whether it makes much sense. I don't think what I wrote is wrong, but I am unsure whether it is "ok" to define the template with incomplete type and only later provide the definition. On the other hand thats the question you didnt ask ;)

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. At the start of the program you can create an object of type Keyboard, and then create EventReader with Keyboard keyboardObject; EventReader<&keyboard> eventReaderObject; eventReaderObject.readEvents(); then it'll call Keyboard object's method. Otherwise if you create the EventReader with nullptr it won't read keyboard events. I'm thinking of doing the same with Mouse and other things. It's basically a callback system but instead of runtime pointers it's compile-time. Does that make sense? Is there something bad about this?

Comment: You can only instantiate a template with an address of a global object or a null pointer.  If you instantiate with an address of a global object, it obviously must be a complete type at this point. It's a way to make a compile-time decision on whether you want keyboard processing, but it seems to be a bit convoluted to me.

Answer (score 3):

> ...it doesn't matter that that class isn't defined anywhere?

You can get a `nullptr` of incomplete type. No problem with that. For example this is a valid program:

```
int main() {
    struct foo;
    foo* x = nullptr;
}
```

> Is this because it isn't needed because when the template argument is nullptr it doesn't generate the call to the member function?

Exactly, the `nullptr` instantiation is equivalent to this

```
struct EventReader_nullptr
{
    void readEvents()
    {
        if (/* Event is keyboard event*/ true)
        {
        }
    }
};
```

The `constexpr` branch is not evaluated. Perhaps this helps to illustrate:

```
template <typename T>
void foo() {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int,T>) {
        static_assert( std::is_same_v<int,T> == false);
    }
}

int main() {
    foo<double>();
}
```

The `static_assert` fires when `T != int`, but it is only evaluated when `T == int`, hence `foo<double>` is fine.

Consider that this function:

```
struct Keyboard;
void foo(Keyboard* p){
    p->receiveInput(4);
}
```

It's a compiler error. You cannot call a method on an incomplete type. There is no danger of UB due to `Keyboard` being incomplete, because the compiler must diagnose it (of course `foo` could still trigger UB with a complete `Keyboard` and a `nullptr` passed).

> Also, I want to be sure that this pointer is not being accessed at runtime, in other words the call to KeyboardObject->receiveInput(4) is exactly the same as:

In the `KeyboardObject<nullptr>` specialization, the pointer is only compared to `nullptr`, but not dereferenced. Only when the template parameter is not `nullptr`, `Keyboard` needs to be complete, because you are calling a member method. Gccs warning

```
<source>:11:31: warning: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Keyboard'
   11 |                 KeyboardObject->receiveInput(4);
      |                               ^~
```

Is a little misleading, because in your code that branch is discarded. I have recently seen similar issue in gcc, where it warns for a discarded branch, which has been fixed in recent versions. In my opinion this one could be "fixed" as well. Anyhow in an instantiation where `KeyboardObject != nullptr` the call to the member is an error.

---

PS: I don't quite understand why you want `Keyboard` incomplete when eventually you want to instantiate `EventReader` with a valid pointer. However, consider that since C++17 you can use an `auto` template argument (unless you want the type always be the same):

```
template <auto KeyboardObject>
struct EventReader
{
    void readEvents()
    {
        if (/* Event is keyboard event*/ true)
        {
            if constexpr (KeyboardObject != nullptr)
                KeyboardObject->receiveInput(4);
        }
    }
};

/* Keyboard class hasn't been defined here*/
EventReader<nullptr> eventReader;

//Keyboard keyboard;
int main()
{
/* Keyboard class hasn't been defined here either */

    eventReader.readEvents(); //
}
```

No forward declaration needed. Actually no declaration of `Keyboard` is need at all, because you are not using it.

Comment: The event reader is supposed to read events from the OS/system, which also includes input device events. If I don't want input devices read then I can choose to pass keyboard or mouse objects or whatever. When you say in the comment you're not sure whether you can do that, to define a template with an incomplete type, I understand that the type isn't needed until the template class is instantiated, which is at the point that you create the object. So when you do EventReader<'KeyboardObjectHere'> myeventreader; then Keyboard needs to be defined, that's all, right?

Comment: @Zebrafish I dont really understand the bigger picture, but I think I'd rather use a type parameter and pass the pointer on construction. Or perhaps provide a factory `template <typename T> T* make_input_device();` which defaults to return a `nullptr` and call that.

Comment: @Zebrafish I know that eg `template <typename T = foo>` is fine when `foo` is incomplete, but I would have to do some research to say something definite for `template <T t>`

Comment: That would call any functions doing dynamic dispatch, right? I was trying to get at compile time by passing the address of the object as a template parameter, at least I think that's what this does.

Comment: @Zebrafish no, nothing dynamic, something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/ohGWbWjEE. Maybe another question is needed to clarify. The specific question here about UB or not with the incomplete type didn't need that background, though there seems to be more beyond that specific question

Comment: @Zebrafish and note that my suggestion to stay away from the non-type template parameter is mainly driven by my limited experience with non-type template parameters ;)

Comment: @Zebrafish ups, previous comment was unclear. When I wrote "do some research to say something definite for template <T t>" i actually mean `<T* t>` and  was refering to `T` being incomplete at the point you define the template, but complete when you instantiate it. For the case in your question I am certain that it is ok